# How to SSH (not exec) into postgres docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh

I want ssh into postgres container here is my dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:password' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

so after running container, I'm doing ssh with command `ssh root@container-ip`, but its saying timeout. I did restart ssh, tried adding other user and allowing user to ssh using `AllowUser username`.
Unable to debug, any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why is this use case important?  PostgreSQL doesn't normally run an ssh server, and in a normal non-Docker scenario you wouldn't ssh into a database but rather use administration tools like `psql`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to establish ssh tunneling.

Comment: You should be able to do this by making an `ssh -L ...:localhost:5432` connection to the host, where the last port number matches the first port number in  a `docker run -p 5432:5432` published-port option.  You don't need the complexity or security challenges of running an sshd in a container to do this.

Comment: Thats great suggestion! Let try the solution you suggested. @DavidMaze